# Sort out IDs when hitting a case

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to sort out ID´s when i have a table like

```
CAR
ID      COLOR
1       Red
1       Black
2       BLUE
2       Black
3       Yellow
3       Red
```

My goal is, that all IDs who have the color "Red" get thrown out, so that just `ID = 2` is my result. With my SQL i can find the IDs which have the Color Red with `Filter = 1` but they still appear because `ID = 1` can also have Black(or ID = 3 can have yellow) so that `Filter = 0` and gets passed.

```
with SORTOUT as
(
ID,
CASE WHEN
COLOR = RED THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS FILTER
FROM TABLE
)
SELECT * FROM ID_TABLE T1
JOIN SORTOUT T2 on (T1.ID = T2.ID)
WHERE FILTER = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the id, use aggregation:

```
select id
from id_table
group by id
having sum(case when color = 'RED' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If you want the original rows, you can use `not exists`:

```
select i.*
from id_table i
where not exists (select 1
                  from id_table i2
                  where i2.id = i.id and i2.color = 'RED'
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, the first SQL seems to fit, even if i dont understand exactly the having sum()-line.

Comment: @TEC23 . . . That is counting the number of rows that have `'RED'` in them.  The `= 0` is saying that there are none.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple select query to achieve this,

```
SELECT * FROM ID_TABLE WHERE COLOR != 'Red';
```

If you still need `CASE` statement, you can use below

```
SELECT ID, COLOR, 
CASE WHEN COLOR = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Val
FROM ID_TABLE WHERE CASE WHEN COLOR = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0;
```

Or

```
SELECT ID, COLOR FROM
(SELECT ID, COLOR, 
CASE WHEN COLOR = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Val
FROM ID_TABLE) qry
WHERE Val = 0;
```

Comment: Those queries will not return just 2

Comment: Probably you can post your expected result. So that can help you

Comment: He writes "...so that just ID = 2 is my result"